# Laravel groupBy violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get all messages for auth user in his inbox with name of people who send him messages.

I have query

```
    $user_id=Auth::id();
    $messages=Chat::with('user')
    ->where('user_id',$user_id)
    ->groupBy('friend_id')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

But Laravel won't me to get that and said:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mojaodeca.chats.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `chats` where `user_id` = 1 group by `friend_id` limit 10)

Comment: where `friend_id` exit in `user` or `chats` ?

Comment: in chats friends_id column exist...query works in phpmyadmin but laravel blocking it

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $user_id=Auth::id();
 $messages=Chat::with('user',function($q){
                     $q->groupBy('friend_id')
                  })
    ->where('user_id',$user_id)
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) - Your select list must be in your aggregate functions.

```
$messages = Chat::select('user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(user_id) as count'))
            ->with('user')
            ->groupBy('friend_id')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mojaodeca.chats.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `user_id`, COUNT(user_id) as count from `chats` group by `friend_id` limit 10)